# License plate horizontal location

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection, object-recognition

A horizontal projection profile is defined as the vector of the sums of the pixel intensities over each row. The image below shows a graph representation of the horizontal projection of the edge image, where the peaks of the graph indicate regions with strong edges and can be used to extract the most likely horizontal positions of the license plate.

But how can I label all the horizontal segments that correspond to significant peaks in the projection profile of the edge image for further vertical location processing?

[image: Horizontal projection of edge image]

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: EasyPR for Chinese License Plate Recognition on Github. https://github.com/liuruoze/EasyPR

Comment: Your question is unclear. You probably mean the vertical positions of the plate. Please confirm. And you already have the limits of the peak. So what more ? And what do you call "to label" ?